# CLion doesn't have CSV file support?

Tags: c++, csv, import, clion, read.csv

I'm new to Clion, switching form Visual Studio and I'm trying to impliment a program that reads in data from a .csv file. However, after I put the file in the directory it doesn't seem to recognize the file. Any resources? I can't find anything on jetBrain about this either. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please show us a [mcve]

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean with "recognize the file". What you you exactly expect?

Comment: For example, when I try to open the file in the directory by double clicking, it does nothing. Or when I try to execute:  
fstream inFile("actor-actress.csv");
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file. \n";
    }
It fails to open the file.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Konafets, I am not quite sure about what your exact problem is, but have you tried installing the [CSV Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10037-csv-plugin) for CLion?

Go to File | Settings | Plugins, type 'csv' in the search bar, click 'Search in repositories' until you land on the [install page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUzKD.jpg).

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to have solved the problem. :)

Comment: @MarcusGallegos Welcome. Perhaps you might want to consider marking your question as answered? - Best